# Explain what this Snowflake syntax is doing

Tags: replace, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Can someone provide a layman's explanation for what the following syntax is doing?

```
select *
,replace(ab.NAME,'""') Name
,replace(ab.CATEGORY_TYPE,'""') Type
,replace(ab.STATUS_ID,'""') Status
from blah
```

I've been reading Snowflake documentation but, from my reading, there should be three arguments within the syntax so...the above isn't really doing anything?

-- Syntax :
REPLACE ( Subject, Pattern, Replacements )

Going by this, the syntax is looking at the data (subject), finding a pattern (pattern), and then there is no third argument (replacement) for what to do if it finds a matching substring? Is this correct?

Comment: Hi - the documentation clearly explains this https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/replace. What don’t you understand about how REPLACE works when the third parameter is omitted?

Answer (score 1):

Based on Snowflake's [documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/replace) for the third parameter of `REPLACE()`:

> This is the value used as a replacement for the pattern. If this is omitted, or is an empty string, then the REPLACE function simply deletes all occurrences of the pattern.

In other words, we could also write your query using empty string as the third parameter:

```sql
SELECT *,
    REPLACE(ab.NAME, '""', '') Name,
    REPLACE(ab.CATEGORY_TYPE, '""', '') Type,
    REPLACE(ab.STATUS_ID, '""', '') Status
FROM blah;
```

Comment: Hmm Ok. So it's removing any empty strings and replacing them with nulls?

Comment: No, your calls to `REPLACE()` are removing `""`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/replace

If replacement is not specified, subject is returned with all occurrences of pattern removed.